# Google App Engine get_serving_url no longer scales up images

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Google App Engine [get_serving_url](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/functions) supposes to allow resize images by appending "=sXX" to the url. It seems to no longer scale up images, i.e. if you gives XX larger than original image dimension, it returns the original image instead of the desired larger size.

Here is an example:

Original image (145x111)
[image: http://lh6.ggpht.com/lC2BVyvToi_zKku5J1Gx_G4NnenfckNOzH_tAkhHovbvsE81S6MGLDtSigEyzUbWSdPkCKlcX7zECHcNlg=s0]
http://lh6.ggpht.com/lC2BVyvToi_zKku5J1Gx_G4NnenfckNOzH_tAkhHovbvsE81S6MGLDtSigEyzUbWSdPkCKlcX7zECHcNlg=s0

Scale up (e.g. to 300px)  - **doesn't work**
[image]

http://lh6.ggpht.com/lC2BVyvToi_zKku5J1Gx_G4NnenfckNOzH_tAkhHovbvsE81S6MGLDtSigEyzUbWSdPkCKlcX7zECHcNlg=s300

Scale down - works
[image]
http://lh6.ggpht.com/lC2BVyvToi_zKku5J1Gx_G4NnenfckNOzH_tAkhHovbvsE81S6MGLDtSigEyzUbWSdPkCKlcX7zECHcNlg=s64

Anyone else experiencing the same thing ?
Funny thing is scaling up used to works and seems to still work on one of my old AppEngine app.

Comment: No longer? I was never able to make it bigger than the original size.

Comment: Indeed, it doesn't. I have been misled to this due to 2 things: 1. Local AppEngine dev server allowing to scale up bigger than original size.

Comment: 2. Due to change in AppEngine get_serving_url, url to images without '=sXX' modification now returns image resized to default 512px (instead of its original size), so when I tried '=s1000' on my old image - it worked but that was due to my old image having larger original size of 1200px

Comment: It is confusing since the local App Engine Dev server scales images up bigger than original size. Any idea why this discrepancy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot resize an image **in order to make it bigger** than the original size `=s0` .

You can do than on the client, by defining the image size via css etc.

Just think why you can't get bigger images. I think because of the following:

> Using `=sxxxx` and requesting from the Blobstore a resized smaller
>   size image **makes sense** because you get a link that will contain a
>   **smaller size image**, that will use **less bandwidth** and will speed up rendering from the client's browser thus achieving **faster**
>   performance.
>
> Getting a bigger sized image from the Blobstore is **useless** because
>   you will use more bandwith and resources for an operation that can
>   also **take place on the client**. You can  use html, css and **javascript** to
>   enlarge the image.

For further operation on images **server-side** use the [Imaging API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/overview) or PIL.

The rest is up to you.